# Insert PBKDF2 hash into PostgreSQL container

Tags: postgresql, psql, docker, hashing

I am using the PostgreSQL docker image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:10.1

COPY init-db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sh
```

and an `init-db.sh` script with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE DATABASE foodb;

    \c foodb;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL,
    username VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    pw VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    super INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_username ON users (username);

INSERT INTO users (username, pw) 
VALUES ('jjolie', 
        'PBKDF2$sha256$901$x8mf3JIFTUFU9C23$ic9J6mFDSz0rETKux/Co9TzCPOX50j+V8Vky5GkY5v0=');
```

After building the container (with the `init-db` script included) with `docker build . --tag postgres`, when the container is started with `docker run postgres`, and the `users` table is viewed:

```
docker exec -it postgres bash
psql -U postgres
\c foodb
select * from users;
```

We see the following output:

```
 id | username |                   pw                    | super
----+----------+-----------------------------------------+-------
  1 | jjolie   | PBKDF201/Co9TzCPOX50j+V8Vky5GkY5v0=     |     0
```

`PBKDF201/Co9TzCPOX50j+V8Vky5GkY5v0=` differs from `PBKDF2$sha256$901$x8mf3JIFTUFU9C23$ic9J6mFDSz0rETKux/Co9TzCPOX50j+V8Vky5GkY5v0='`.

Why did the password change from `PBKDF2$...` to `PBKDF201..`? How can it be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the variables are replaced (with nothing) in bash, the dollars signs need to be escaped:

```
'PBKDF2\$sha256\$901\$x8mf3JIFTUFU9C23\$ic9J6mFDSz0rETKux/Co9TzCPOX50j+V8Vky5GkY5v0='
```

Comment: Alternatively, he could open the heredoc with `<<-'EOSQL'`, which will suppress the variable substitution without needing to introduce an additional layer of escaping to the data itself